# Trying to dismiss a view controller by tap on cancel using delegation (Not working at all)

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, delegation, popviewcontroller

Having two view controller within a navigation controller:

`PhoneNumbersTVC` > holds a list of phone numbers added by `NewPhoneNumberTVC`
`NewPhoneNumberTVC` > a controller for adding phone numbers

When I tap on cancel on `NewPhoneNumberTVC` I like to get back to `PhoneNumbersTVC` with a delegation as follow.

**PhoneNumbersTVC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NewPhoneNumberTVC.h"

@interface PhoneNumbersTVC : UITableViewController <NewPhoneNumberTVCDelegate>

@end
```

**PhoneNumbersTVC.m**

```
- (void)saveBtnWasTappedOnNewPhoneNumberTVC:(NewPhoneNumberTVC *)newPhoneNumberTVC
{
    NSLog(@"saveBtnWasTappedOnNewPhoneNumberTVC");
    [newPhoneNumberTVC.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)cancelBtnWasTappedOnNewPhoneNumberTVC:(NewPhoneNumberTVC *)newPhoneNumberTVC
{
    NSLog(@"cancelBtnWasTappedOnNewPhoneNumberTVC");
    [newPhoneNumberTVC.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**NewPhoneNumberTVC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class NewPhoneNumberTVC;

@protocol NewPhoneNumberTVCDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)saveBtnWasTappedOnNewPhoneNumberTVC:(NewPhoneNumberTVC *)newPhoneNumberTVC;
- (void)cancelBtnWasTappedOnNewPhoneNumberTVC:(NewPhoneNumberTVC *)newPhoneNumberTVC;

@end


@interface NewPhoneNumberTVC : UITableViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <NewPhoneNumberTVCDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedOC;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *phoneNumberTextField;

- (IBAction)saveBtnTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
- (IBAction)cancelBtnTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

@end
```

**NewPhoneNumberTVC.m**

```
- (IBAction)cancelBtnTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"cancelBtnTapped");
    self.phoneNumberTextField.text = @"";
    self.phoneKindTextField.text = @"";
    [self.delegate cancelBtnWasTappedOnNewPhoneNumberTVC:self];
```

}

When I tap on cancel on `NewPhoneNumberTVC` I see that above method `cancelBtnTapped` fires but `delegation` does not work, no `method` executes in `PhoneNumbersTVC`. View doesn't go away and I don't see: `cancelBtnWasTappedOnNewPhoneNumberTVC` on `console`.

Comment: Are you sure you have set the delegate? If yes, at what time you are setting the delegate?

Comment: WHere did you set the delegate of NewPhoneNumberTVC?

Comment: @lu yuam I tell the delegate that cancel was tapped in method: `cancelBtnTapped`  `[self.delegate cancelBtnWasTappedOnNewPhoneNumberTVC:self];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this method `cancelBtnWasTappedOnNewPhoneNumberTVC:` get called, you definitely need to set the delegate of your `NewPhoneNumberTVC` object to a `PhoneNumbersTVC` object. For example, there should be existing some codes in **PhoneNumbersTVC.m** :

```
NewPhoneNumberTVC *myNewPhoneNumberTVC = [[NewPhoneNumberTVC alloc] init];
myNewPhoneNumberTVC.delegate = self;
```

You can log as following to verify that the delegate is set successfully or not"

**NewPhoneNumberTVC.m**

```
- (IBAction)cancelBtnTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
NSLog(@"cancelBtnTapped");
self.phoneNumberTextField.text = @"";
self.phoneKindTextField.text = @"";
NSLog(@"self.delegate :%@",self.delegate);
[self.delegate cancelBtnWasTappedOnNewPhoneNumberTVC:self];
}
```

Comment: Just found it myself. Totally forgot. Thanks!